# The unknown escape character issue when using YAML in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, yaml

I have the following text (one of the cells in pandas dataframe) that creates trouble when converting it to a json dictionary type:

```
 {"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{},
  "overall_feedback":"...and that\'s something I want to learn too. ",
  "submission_uuid":"b195603a-60f5-11e4-95a7-0a7da95da37f"}
```

The code I am using is this:

```
df['POST'] = df['POST'].apply(yaml.load)
```

It throws the following error:

```
found unknown escape character "'"
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 174:
     ... that\'s something I want to learn too ...
```

When I print that specific cell, this is what I got

```
df.ix[7, 'POST']

>> that\\\'s
```

I have checked already other relevant questions in SO and the YAML guide, but could not figure out what the solution is. Can someone help please?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to apply `YAML` instead of `JSON`. Try `json.loads` instead

Comment: @MaxU thanks! just got a similar error `Invalid \escape: line 1 column 173`!

Comment: @MaxU: note that YAML is a superset of JSON. That is, a YAML parser will parse any valid JSON document.

Comment: @larsks, thank you! I didn't know that

Comment: @renakre: that `'` doesn't need to be escaped (because the string is enclosed in *double* quotes, so there's nothing special about `'`).  If you just replace it with `"overall_feedback":"...and that's something I want to learn too. "` it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to remove the escaped character first because JSON doesn't allow it.

```
import json

j = '{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{}, "overall_feedback":"...and that\'s something I want to learn too. ", "submission_uuid":"b195603a-60f5-11e4-95a7-0a7da95da37f"}'

json.loads(j.replace("\\'", "'"))
```

Edit:

as @larks said in the comment,

> that `'` doesn't need to be escaped (because the string is enclosed in *double* quotes)

and indeed your problem is hard to reproduce:

```
import yaml
import json

data = """
    options_selected: 
        Ideas: '0'
    criterion_feedback: {}
    overall_feedback": ...and that\'s something I want to learn too. ,
    submission_uuid : b195603a-60f5-11e4-95a7-0a7da95da37f
"""

print yaml.load(data)

j = '{"options_selected":{"Ideas":"0"},"criterion_feedback":{}, "overall_feedback":"...and that\'s something I want to learn too. ", "submission_uuid":"b195603a-60f5-11e4-95a7-0a7da95da37f"}'

print json.loads(j)
```

will both output:

```
{'overall_feedback"': "...and that's something I want to learn too. ,", 'submission_uuid': 'b195603a-60f5-11e4-95a7-0a7da95da37f', 'options_selected': {'Ideas': '0'}, 'criterion_feedback': {}}
```